# How to fetch value of another table if we have only its id in First table?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I don't know how to explain the problem I am facing in laravel 4.2.
Eg:

1. I have two tables `tasktime` and `category`.
2. Category table has three fields `id, cat_id, categoryname`.
3. In `tasktime` table I am inserting `cat_id` like this:

   ```php
   <option value="{{$user->cat_id}}" >{{$user->categoryname}}</option>
   ```
4. On view page it should show like this-> cat_id/categoryname

There are two table category and tasktime.I am inserting cat_id of category table to tasktime table.But I want to fetch value category name from that cat_id which has been inserted into tasktime table

Now I want that the user can see all the values that are in `tasktime` but with `categoryname` of that particular `cat_id` which is inserted into `tasktime` table.

Comment: What are the fields of the tasktime table?

Comment: What is the name attribute of your `<select>` element?

Comment: What do you want to fetch from the database? All tasktimes with a certain cat_id?

Comment: I want to fetch category name(which is in category table)  from cat_id of tasktime table.

Comment: tasktime table has tasktitle,description,cat_id,pic,user_id

Comment: from database i want to fetch cat_id along with category name that belong to that particular cat_id

Comment: Why does the category table have both an `id` field and a `cat_id` field? Is one a foreign key to some other table?

Comment: Is `tasktime.cat_id` foreign keyed to `category.id` or `category.cat_id`?

Comment: name attribute of select element is taskcategory.Which is showing category name on view page.But when any user submit task cat_id is inserted into taktime table

Comment: yes tasktime.cat_id is foreign key

Comment: there are two table category and tasktime.I am inserting cat_id of category table to tasktime table.But I want to fetch value category name from that cat_id which has been inserted into tasktime table.On view page it should show like this-> cat_id/categoryname